# regarding variable argument in python

Tags: python

i am writing a class in python and in that i am calling a function to display variable argument.In the beginning the function calculates the sum of integers.

When i am calling the function without any class,then it is printing the values but inside the class,it is throwing error.

```
def displayString(name, msg = "Good morning!"):

   print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)

displayString("Kate")
displayString("Bruce","How do you do?")
```

the above is displaying the result but when 
i am calling the function inside the class below, it is throwing error

```
class new:


    answer=0
    def __init__(self,f,s):

        self.first=f
        self.second=s

    def display(self):

        print("this is the first ={} and the second={} value".format(self.first,self.second))
        print("the answer is {}".format(self.answer))

    def calculate(self):

        self.answer=self.first+self.second

    def displayString(name, msg = "Good morning!"):
        print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)


if __name__=="__main__":

    x=new(1,2)
    x.calculate()
    x.display()
    x.displayString("kate")
    x.displayString("micky","How are you?")
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-fd51df6426ac> in <module>
     26     x.calculate()
     27     x.display()
---> 28     x.displayString("kate")
     29     x.displayString("micky","How are you?")
     30 

<ipython-input-38-fd51df6426ac> in displayString(name, msg)
     18 
     19     def displayString(name, msg = "Good morning!"):
---> 20         print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)
     21 
     22 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'new' and 'str'
```

Comment: Inside a class this should be `def displayString(self, name, msg = "Good morning!")`

Answer (score 3):

When you put the  function inside the class, it becomes a method. Python methods by default require a `self` parameter. The name `self` has no special meaning, so when you missed out the the `self` argument, it passed the same value that it otherwise would have passed to the `self` parameter into the first argument, `name`, causing the error when you tried to add the reference to the object (stored in `name`) to a string: `name + ', '`

There are two ways to fix this. This most obvious is to add the self parameter:

```
class new:
    def displayString(self, name, msg = "Good morning!"):
        print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)


if __name__=="__main__":
    x = new()
    x.displayString("kate")
    x.displayString("micky","How are you?")
```

The second is to stop python from passing in the `self` argument by using the `staticmethod` decorator:

```
class new:
    @staticmethod
    def displayString(name, msg = "Good morning!"):
        print("Hello",name + ', ' + msg)


if __name__=="__main__":
    x = new()
    x.displayString("kate")
    x.displayString("micky","How are you?")
```